# Why is my computer failing to download all kinds of files on all browsers?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, wifi-configuration, file-download

The network itself is brand new and quite fast. Unfortunately bigger files are throwing a 'Network Failure' error after different amounts of time.

Smaller files get the error also but most times are able to finish without error.

My Connection is the following:

```
Computer with Fritz Wi-Fi Adapter AC 460 -> FritzBox 7590.
```

I successfully managed to recreate the problem with

- Multiple Browsers: Edge and Chrome
- And different Wi-Fi Adapters

Didn't manage to reproduce the problem with my laptop or phone connected to the same router, so it's definitely my momputer.

Anybody has a clue? I spend hours searching the web and even once reinstalled Windows but the problem reappeared after some time.

Comment: So what happens when you try? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Edited the initial post

Comment: Try a TCP/IP Reset / DNS Flush .   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer   and test.

Comment: hey @John, it worked like magic, how did you know and why didn't I stumble upon this fix before. I'll read into these commands tomorrow, thank you, sir. You just saved me plenty of nerves

Comment: How large is a "large file"? Anything over 2GB you should always use a download manager that will spilt files into smaller segments. Many ISPs invisibly cache large files on their way through & manage to mess up if they exceed 2GB. This ought to be less of an issue than it was a decade ago, but your ISP will never tell you if they use this method still.

Comment: the files are between 200-900MB. Smaller files are downloaded most times too fast to produce this error with 20MB/s. sometimes the error still accures with smaller files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most issues as you have can be solved by a TCP/IP Reset / DNS Flush.  I have done this for a number of similar issues over the years.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

1. `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`
2. `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. restart the computer and test.

You may also wish to / need to update the Fritz Stick Driver so as to avoid future problems.

Comment: Edit: seems like the FritzStick driver messing with it. Straight after restart finished multiple big downloads with no error. Couple of minutes later got the same problems as before, ran the commands, restarted, and disabled the autostart of the Wi-Fi stick software and the problem is still gone so far. The problem with having the software off is that zoom and games are lagging, even tho the ping is <10ms, but I'll give it a thorough try tomorrow during the day

Comment: After trying tomorrow. post any issues.  Is there a Fritz Stick driver that you can update. I would do that as well. I added that to my answer.

Comment: So after rebooting today the same error was thrown while downloading as before the fix.
Ran the commands. IP reset, DNS flush. Restarted. When I'm trying to continue the interrupted file from before restart it shows the same behavior, restarting a fresh file is working perfectly fine (probably till next restart). 
Shall I write a batch script executing this commands after/before every shutdown/wakeup or is there a better solution?

Comment: You can put the commands in Task Scheduler and run at elevated permissions at log off or shut down (same thing) .  Log a support call with Fritz to get a resolution. Standard TCP/IP is very vanilla, it works for you, and Fritz is screwing it up for you.

Comment: i put the script into :\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff and added it in mmc - Script-In adding -  group guidelines editor and am currently struggling with executing it as an admin. If just planned as regular task i was unable to choose the shutdown as a trigger and with my way I'm struggling executing it as an admin

Comment: That is why I suggest Task Scheduler. You do have to set up up the task but that allows you to set Elevated Permissions, provide the credentials, and then the Task script will run without further interaction. Task scripts are used by Vendors to set up once and allow regular users to run.

Comment: managed to find the shutdown trigger under Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Perfomance with the ID 200, who would've thought it's that hidden. sorry for the eternal question bombardment. Hope it'll work from now on

Comment: No issue - I am happy to help you and good luck with the trigger.

Comment: Hey @John, I didn't restart and am getting the same errors already again, any clue what to do?

Comment: Try Task Scheduler . It works quite reliably.