# McAfee Real-time Scanning blocks download of MS Office documents

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-office, download

**Update:** I contacted McAfee. This is a known issue they are working to resolve.

I am unable to download Microsoft Office documents to my computer (PDFs download fine). When I try to download the files (from Gmail, Google Drive, or [another website](https://professional.heart.org/-/media/phd-files/research/research-programs/application-information/aha_reference_report_pre_post_doctoral.doc?la=en)) the file appears in the Chrome download ribbon like normal, but the blue circle around the file icon never goes away:

[image: chrome_download_ribbon]

In the Chrome download list (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) it appears that the  file is fully downloaded (207 KB of 207 KB) but not "completed":

[image: chrome_download_list_2]

If I try to close Chrome at this point, I get this message:
Downloads are in progress
Exit Chrome anyway?

[image: chrome_exit_warning]

Sometimes, an icon for the file appears in the download directory. However, the Chrome download list doesn't change, and I still get the warning above if I try to close Chrome. If I close Chrome before I edit the file, the icon disappears. When the icon does appear, sometimes the contents of the file can be seen in the Win10 preview pane:

[image: file_preview_pane]

When I try to open the file, it takes a very long time for the file to open (and sometimes Word crashes). If I edit the file and then close Chrome, the file doesn't disappear and from then on I can open the file normally.

When I use Edge to download the file on the same computer, an `Unconfirmed###.download` file appears in the download directory, but the download never completes. When I use Chrome to download the file on a different computer, the file downloads without any issues.

Any ideas what is causing this issue? I tried the TCP/IP Reset / DNS Flush suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609630/why-is-my-computer-failing-to-download-all-kinds-of-files-on-all-browsers), with no luck. Thanks!

**System:**

- Processor        Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz   2.40 GHz
- Installed RAM    32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
- System type      64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Edition          Windows 10 Home
- Version          20H2
- Installed on ‎04/‎14/‎2021
- OS build     19042.1165
- Experience       Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0

**Security providers (Win10 terminology):**

- Antivirus

  - McAfee VirusScan is turned on.
  - Microsoft Defender Antivirus is turned off.
- Firewall

  - McAfee Firewall is turned on.
  - Windows Firewall is turned off.
- Web protection No providers

**Antivirus:**

- McAfee® Total Protection
- Version: 16.0
- Release Name: 16.0 R36
- McAfee Security Center
- Affld: 1276
- Build: 19.6.169
- Language: en-us
- Last update: 8/18/2021
- Version: 19.6

**Update related to comments**
When I try to exclude the downloading file from McAfee's real-time scan, only these file types are eligible:

[image: mcafee_exclude_options]

Comment: You should try creating an exception for the download location. Your AV signatures are 5 days out of date.

Comment: @Ramhound, I just manually ran the McAfee update and 08/18/2021 is the latest update. What do you mean by create an exception? I want to be able to download to any directory.

Comment: For the time being create an exception for your desktop, so the AV, doesn’t block the download

Comment: Once you start to download the Office files, please try to [exclude them from virus scans](https://service.mcafee.com/?articleId=TS102056&page=shell&shell=article-view).

Comment: @Emily, the McAfee will only allow me to exclude .exe, .dll, .jar, and .pdf files (image of drop-down added to OP.

Comment: @Ramhound, disabling McAfee real-time scanning solved the problem. Is there a way to solve the problem while retaining real-time scanning? Thanks!

Comment: There is, make an exception for the download location, or determine the feature within your AV that’s causing the problem.  You should be able to create an exception for the entire folder. Be sure any browser extensions are disabled

Comment: According to McAfee: "We are facing some technical challenges, which is the root cause of the issue you are experiencing. Our research team is working to fix the issue. we will get back you once we get the resolution for this issue." Until they fix the issue, I'll use the work-around from @Ramhound. Thanks!

Comment: tbh, McAfee has long been the dumbest, least configurable Windows antivirus. I'd call it time to change allegiance. Almost anything will be better. Avira, Avast, AVG, BitDefender, … you name it… See https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/

Comment: @Tetsujin, I don't have any special allegiance to McAfee, but that list (https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/windows-10/april-2021/) appears to be in alphabetical order, not ranked order. McAfee and Avast were both 6/6 for Protection, Performance, and Usability.

Comment: They’re in order of which header you click… but there’s no column measuring ‘cussedness’ ;)

Comment: Ha! @Tetsujin, I wish I could give you an upvote for introducing me to Tim Minchin's Storm.

Comment: I’m just happy to be able to introduce someone else to him. Listen to his other stuff, he’s got a sharp mind …& can play piano a bit too:)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me too.  I just contacted McAfee technical support, and they said the issue would be resolved in their next software update, scheduled for September 28.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Users need 50 reputation to post comments.