# Having persistent "download failed" issues in all browsers in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, download

I am having "download failed" error in all browsers (tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge) whenever I try to download files. By resuming download, it eventually completes, but the process often stops due to the error.

The errors look like this:

on firefox

[image: 1]

on chrome

[image: 2]

on edge

[image: 3]

My internet speed is 53Mbps for download so I don't think it's particularly slow. The file sizes aren't too large either, as I got the error when downloading 5MB file.

The connection is via Wi-Fi, and the adapter's driver is up to date.
I couldn't recreate the same problem in other computers connected to the same router so I'm quite confident that the problem is with my computer.

I have tried [TCP/IP reset and DNS](https://superuser.com/questions/1609630/why-is-my-computer-failing-to-download-all-kinds-of-files-on-all-browsers) Flush with no success.

My Windows 10 is Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044

I have a suspicion that the problem might be related with https, because when I tried NMKD Stable Diffusion GUI, I got the error that suggests https related issue. The NMKD GUI error I got

[image: the NMKD GUI error I got]

Thank you for reading, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it also happen in Chrome Incognito Mode ?

Comment: yes, tried incognito mode and external download manager, but same "download failed due to network error" happens

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Have you tried the usual fixes, Network troubleshooter, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-network-connection-issues-in-windows-166a28c4-14c1-bdb1-473c-09c1571455d8, SFC and DISM? Also look to see if another process is interrupting (e.g., malware).

Comment: @harrymc I added error messages.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have tried Network trouble shooter, SFC scan and DISM, but it doesn't seem solved the issue.

Comment: The error "decryption failed or bad record mac" is typically an  SSL error and arrives when something tampers with the communication. What is this `nmkd` in the error message?

Comment: @harrymc, NMKD GUI is a software to run text-to-image model Stable Diffusion, made by a developer named N00MKRAD. When I tried to run this GUI, I got the error shown in the image. Sorry, I should have been explained more clearly.

Comment: also, I tried clearing SSL slate, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you asked the developer for help? The [Readme](https://github.com/n00mkrad/text2image-gui/blob/main/README.md#system-requirements) also mentioned re-install methods which could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My computer connected to internet using wifi. I had tried to download using some browsers, but it kept failed. Then, I disconnected the wifi, and switch to "usb tethering" using my smarthphone. Problem solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240826)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).